# Does PCI for IA64 architecture require a different kind of PCI card or just a different kind of a driver?

Tags: pci, itanium

I have a machine that is IA64 and it has a spot for PCI cards in it.  I was wondering if the PCI cards in it can be just regular PCI cards, or if they have to be PCI cards that were built specifically to work with an IA64 architecture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PCI port is the same but the firmware on the card required for them to be recognised in an IA64 box needs to be IA64-aware - so no, not every PCI card will 'just work' in an IA64 machine, it'd need drivers too of course.